# how to get status code other than 200 from scrapy-splash

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I am trying to get request status code with scrapy and scrapy-splash,below is spider code.

```
class Exp10itSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "exp10it"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
                'http://192.168.8.240:8000/xxxx' 
        ]
        for url in urls:
            #yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5, 'dont_redirect': True},meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})
            #yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True,'splash': {
                'args': {
                    'html': 1,
                    'png': 1,
                    }
            }
            }
            )


    def parse(self, response):
        input("start .........")
        print("status code is:\n")
        input(response.status)
```

My start url `http://192.168.8.240:8000/xxxx` is a 404 status code url,there are threee kinds of request way upon:

the first is:

```
yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5, 'dont_redirect': True},meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})
```

the second is:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})
```

the third is:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True,'splash': {
            'args': {
                'html': 1,
                'png': 1,
                }
        }
        }
        )
```

Only the second request way `yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})` can get the right status code `404`,the first and the third both get status code `200`,that's to say,after I try to use scrapy-splash,I can not get the right status code `404`,can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to `scrapy-splash` suggests, you have to pass `magic_response=True` to `SplashRequest` to achieve this:

> `meta['splash']['http_status_from_error_code']` - set `response.status` to HTTP error code when `assert(splash:go(..))` fails; it requires `meta['splash']['magic_response']=True`. `http_status_from_error_code` option is `False` by default if you use raw meta API; `SplashRequest` sets it to `True` by default.

**EDIT:**
I was able to get it to work only with `execute` endpoint, though. Here is sample spider that tests HTTP status code using [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import scrapy_splash

class HttpStatusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'httpstatus'

    lua_script = """
    function main(splash, args)
      assert(splash:go(args.url))
      assert(splash:wait(0.5))
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
        png = splash:png(),
      }
    end
    """

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy_splash.SplashRequest(
            'https://httpbin.org/status/402', self.parse,
            endpoint='execute',
            magic_response=True,
            meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True},
            args={'lua_source': self.lua_script})

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

It passes the HTTP 402 status code to Scrapy, as can be seen from the output:

```
...
2017-10-23 08:41:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (402) <GET https://httpbin.org/status/402 via http://localhost:8050/execute> (referer: None)
...
```

You can experiment with other HTTP status codes as well.

Comment: I try to use below code with http_status_from_error_code=True,but still fails.
            ```yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True, 'splash': {
                'args': {
                    'html': 1,
                    'png': 1,
                },
                'magic_response': True,
                'http_status_from_error_code': True
            }
            }
            )```

Comment: Why don't you use `SplashRequest`? It's the recommended way of using Splash with Scrapy.

Comment: I try to use SplashRequest with below code,but still fails.`yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5, 'dont_redirect': True}, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})
` Am I using it not correctly?

Comment: Try `yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5, 'dont_redirect': True}, magic_response=True, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})`

Comment: `yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5, 'dont_redirect': True}, magic_response=True, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})` still fails,the return status code is 200 again,not 404

Comment: In your example url `https://httpbin.org/status/402`,the request result is:`response.status=402`,but `response.body` is not the correct content `Fuck you, pay me!`,can you help me?

Comment: You reached my limit ;-) Don't know.